# absolute layout in scroll view on android

Tags: android

i want to Android xml design in the following format i did but it does not work.

xml layout:coding

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/widget836"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget837" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ImageView>
        </TableLayout>
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView111"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/widget883"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="303px"
                    android:layout_height="56px" android:text="Email" android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_x="1px" android:layout_y="15px">
                </EditText>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/pass" android:layout_width="303px"
                    android:layout_height="56px" android:text="password"
                    android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_x="3px" android:layout_y="57px">
                </EditText>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/enter" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Enter an email address and password above, and your accout will be created."
                    android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="65px">
                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/primarydisplay"
                    android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_height="40px"
                    android:text="Primary Display" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="75px">
                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/gps" android:layout_width="100px"
                    android:layout_height="40px" android:text="Speed >"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_x="200px" android:layout_y="75px">
                </TextView>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
            <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/widget884"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/distanceunit"
                    android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_height="40px"
                    android:text="Distance Unit" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="85px">
                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/miles" android:layout_width="100px"
                    android:layout_height="40px" android:text="Miles >"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_x="200px" android:layout_y="85px">
                </TextView>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Log cat error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

pleae correct me.

Comment: dude you can add only one child view within scrollview so just put that two absolute layout in a single layout and add it inside scroll view. that's it.

Comment: hi 
how to combine to Absloute Layout into one.? please correct me

Comment: just put that two layout inside one linearlayout and then add it inside scrollview

Comment: hi
i combine two absolute layout but the second absolute only displayed by without scroll. have i set height and width for absolute layout. now it has  fill_parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one direct child element in a `Scrollview` so you should either combine your two `AbsoluteLayout` elements or you should wrap them in another element such as another `AbsoluteLayout` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/widget836"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget837" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>
    </TableLayout>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView111"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- Wrap -->
        <AbsoluteLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/widget883"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <EditText android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="303px"
                android:layout_height="56px" android:text="Email" android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_x="1px" android:layout_y="15px">
              </EditText>
              <EditText android:id="@+id/pass" android:layout_width="303px"
                android:layout_height="56px" android:text="password"
                android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_x="3px" android:layout_y="57px">
              </EditText>

              <TextView android:id="@+id/enter" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Enter an email address and password above, and your accout will be created."
                android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="65px">
              </TextView>
              <TextView android:id="@+id/primarydisplay"
                android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_height="40px"
                android:text="Primary Display" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="75px">
              </TextView>
              <TextView android:id="@+id/gps" android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="40px" android:text="Speed >"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_x="200px" android:layout_y="75px">
              </TextView>
          </AbsoluteLayout>
          <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/widget884"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
              <TextView android:id="@+id/distanceunit"
                android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_height="40px"
                android:text="Distance Unit" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="85px">
              </TextView>
              <TextView android:id="@+id/miles" android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="40px" android:text="Miles >"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_x="200px" android:layout_y="85px">
              </TextView>
          </AbsoluteLayout>

        </AbsoluteLayout>
        <!-- /Wrap -->
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi
i got all merged upper image is  not shown. how to combine to Absloute Layout into one.? please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `ScrollView` is designed for a single child element. Yours contains two `AbsoluteLayout`s. Can these views be merged?

Answer (score -1):

i am not clear why you want to use two Absolute Layouts inside a scroll view......

Put them in a single layout

Also note that the use of AbsoluteLayout is deprecated. Try using Relative or Linear Layouts instead...

Comment: because i want to draw rounded rectangle background for two absolute layout as per design.

Comment: @murali why you need a scrollview.....Are you adding new components dynamically. 

I mentioned this because your current xml components will fill the screen and so there is no need for a scrollView